# C++: unpack the data back again

Tags: c++

I'm packing my string with this function:

```
std::vector<char> pack(const std::string& str) {
    const uint32_t sz = str.size();
    const uint32_t n_sz = htonl(sz);
    std::vector<char> result(sizeof(sz) + sz);
    memcpy(result.data(), &n_sz, sizeof(n_sz));
    memcpy(result.data() + sizeof(sz), str.data(), sz);
    return result;
}
```

How can i unpack it again so...i get the original string back?

I tried to do:

```
 int len;
    len = ntohl(ourbuffer.size());

    char* string = (    char*  )malloc(sizeof (char) * (len + 1));
    string[len] = '\0';
```

becouse i know the function pack is using big endian. But that did not work. Can someone please show how to to unpack again??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uint32_t n_sz;
memcpy(&n_sz, ourbuffer.data(), sizeof n_sz);
const uint32_t sz = ntohl(n_sz);
std::string str(ourbuffer.data() + sizeof n_sz, sz);
```

Comment: Hmm that give a lot sense and works, thank you and to everyone else who helped me!